# How to call an element from a 2D array in this scenario?

Tags: python

```
data = [['01','Book',5],['02','Pen',2],['03','Pencil',1.5],['04','Paper',15],['05','USB Drive',20]]
```

- first element in each secondary list is the product ID
- second element is the product name
- third element is the product price.

Prompt the user to enter a product name and a quantity. Repeat this as many times as he/she wants. 
Compute and display the quantities, names, and prices of the products entered by the user.
Compute and display the total cost of purchasing those products.

```
more = 'yes'
shopping_list = []
while more == 'yes':
    user_input = input('Enter a product:')
    user_quantity = int(input('Enter the number of products:'))
    shopping_list.append(user_input)
    shopping_list.append(user_quantity)
    more = input('Would you like more?')
```

My code doesn't work..

Comment: Side note: those are not arrays, those are lists.

Comment: Does `data` need to be formatted like that? Would be way easier if it was a list

Comment: data has to be formatted like a 2D list. And @timgeb, my code doesn't allow me to have the following output: You have ordered:
100 Pen: $2
5 USB Drive: $20
10 Book: $5

Comment: data = [['01','Book',5],['02','Pen',2],['03','Pencil',1.5],['04','Paper',15],['05','USB Drive',20]]
more = "y"
while more == "y":
    prod = input("Enter product name: ")
    quant = input("Enter quantity: ")
    more = input("Enter another product (y/n)? ")
for x in data:
    if prod == x[1]:
        print("You have ordered:")
        print(quant,x[1],": $",int(quant)*int(x[2]))
another way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would format the data to keep it in a dictionary with unique key being the product_name and value being the price

```
formatted_data={j:k for i,j,k in data}
```

formatted data would look like:

> {'Book': 5, 'Paper': 15, 'Pen': 2, 'Pencil': 1.5, 'USB Drive': 20}

```
more = 'yes'
shopping_list = []
while more == 'yes':
    user_input = input('Enter a product:')
    user_quantity = int(input('Enter the number of products:'))
    if user_input in formatted_data:
        get_price_of_product=formatted_data[user_input]
        get_quantity=user_quantity
        amount=get_price_of_product * get_quantity
        shopping_list.append((user_input,amount))
    else:
        print('Enter valid product name')
    more = input('Would you like more?')
```

Comment: "Enter a product:" - "pencil" - #looks up 'pencil' in dictionary of {'01'-'05'}# #melts#

Comment: @IcedLance Edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [['01','Book',5],['02','Pen',2],['03','Pencil',1.5],['04','Paper',15],['05','USB Drive',20]]
data_dict = {i[0]:[i[1],i[2]] for i in data}
shopping_list = {}
while True:
    try:
        user_input = input('Enter a product:')
        user_quantity = int(input('Enter the number of products:'))
        shopping_list[user_input] = [data_dict[user_input][0], user_quantity,user_quantity*data_dict[user_input][1]]
        more = input('Would you like more?')
        if more == 'no':
            break
    except KeyError:
        print('We dont have this ID. Try again')
```